Binance. Error -1102, Mandatory parameter 'signature' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed
I'm creating a bot at binance that buy and sell crypto this is just part of the code that creates new order but is giving error in signature, and i think the binance buy a cripto and pay the taxes using the crypto you had when you buy and sell i think i need to include this too. I tried this stuff below and didn't work, I couldn't figure it out
{"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}
async function novaOrdem(symbol, quantity, side, price) {
  const type = 'MARKET';
  const recvWindow = 5000;
  const commissionRates = await getCommissionRates(symbol);
  const commission = side === 'BUY' ? commissionRates.standardCommission.buyer : commissionRates.standardCommission.seller;
  const tax = side === 'BUY' ? commissionRates.taxCommission.buyer : commissionRates.taxCommission.seller;
  const discount = commissionRates.discount.discount;
  const priceWithCommission = price * (1 + parseFloat(commission) + parseFloat(tax) - parseFloat(discount));

  const params = { symbol, quantity, side, type, price: priceWithCommission, timestamp: Date.now(), recvWindow };
  const queryString = Object.keys(params).map(key => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`).join('&');
  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', CHAVE_SECRETA).update(queryString).digest('hex');

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/v3/order`, null, {
      params: { ...params, signature },
      headers: { 'X-MBX-APIKEY': CHAVE_API }
    });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (erro) {
    console.error('Erro ao colocar a ordem:', erro.response.data);
  }
}


I fixed i needed to change the all to one query string, the binance query string shoud look like this symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559

I just formatted the in one just query string and it worked
async function novaOrdem(symbol, quantity, side, price) {
  const type = 'MARKET';
  const recvWindow = 5000;
  const timestamp = Date.now();

  const params = { symbol, side, type, quantity, price, recvWindow, timestamp };
  const queryString = Object.keys(params)
    .sort()
    .map(key => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`)
    .join('&');
  
  const signature = cripto.createHmac('sha256', CHAVE_SECRETA).update(queryString).digest('hex');

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/v3/order`, null, {
      params: { ...params, signature },
      headers: { 'X-MBX-APIKEY': CHAVE_API }
    });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (erro) {
    console.error('Erro ao colocar a ordem:', erro.response.data);
  }
}

